# Remove and secure /admin/ from google search

Tags: php, html

I have a custom designed script for my website, and /admin/ shows up in google search. How can i make /admin/ not visible and knowable to others. At least on google or searchable?

Comment: You can add a robots.txt file to tell properly coded search engines to ignore or include specific directories.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/block-indexing
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is return a `404 not found` unless the user is already logged in.  Put the login url above /admin.

That combined with [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) should take care of it.

However, using robots.txt will alert those with ill-intent (hackers, etc) that you have a url to be attacked.  I never put admin dashboards in robots.txt - I simply deny they exist.

```
<?php

$loggedIn = false; // replace with how you track logged in status
if ( ! $loggedIn )
{
    header( 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found' );
    echo '<h1>404 - Not Found</h1>';
    exit();
}
```

Comment: So what would be the best way for the folder not to be searchable? And then should i just change /admin/ folder?

Comment: admin/index.php would send a 404 response if the visitor wasn't a logged in admin level user.

Comment: Also, don't provide any links to (for example) http://example.com/admin/ from the public parts of your site.

Comment: Yeah but how do i make it 404? Also yeah, i mean i wont provide the admin link. But wont google eventually find it and put it in google search?

Comment: Google will remove a url that has a 404 error - will edit answer to show how to send 404.

Comment: Ahhh okay awesome. Yea im curious as to that. Is there other ways to make it more secure as well? Or its the best way?

Comment: How would i be able to login though if it returns a 404?

Comment: re: security - you should use SSL (HTTPS) for all logged in pages on your site. That's the #1 best way to improve security.  Helps to prevent [session hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack)

Comment: you have to have your login url elsewhere.  the login script redirects to the /admin url after you're logged in.

Comment: So i login through another php file say for example loginhere.php and it redirects me into /admin/ once logged in?

Comment: Awesome that actually really sounds good. It works really well i assume?

Comment: I've used this technique for years. :)

Comment: Haha awesome. Any other precautions maybe or is this efficient?

Comment: here's a list of things you should be doing (google them if you don't know - this is not the place to discuss :) )  PDO with parameterized queries, SSL, hashed & salted passwords in your database, an understanding of all the session cookie parameters available in PHP.

Comment: Yeah im going to research all this for sure. Thank you so mmuch though i love your redirect 404 idea.

Answer (score 4):

As already stated by andrewsi, you create a robots.txt file and put the following:

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /admin
```

Place that in the root of your site.

Comment: As an aside.... It's probably better to use explicit Allow lines in your robots.txt - if there are directories you don't want people knowing about, you might not want to list them all in your robots.txt file for miscreants to see.

Comment: So what would be the best way for the folder not to be searchable? And then should i just change /admin/ folder?

Answer (score 1):

create a file called `robots.txt` and place it in the root of your website.
Add the following to it:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
```

this is all explained in more detail on [robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `robots.txt` file with the following:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
```

Not all crawlers obey this file, however.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449